# How to return a listmap with non null item, from a map?

Tags: kotlin

I have a piece of code as below (simplified to explain the issue). From the rawData, I would like to filter out those that doesn't have a converter type provided in `converter`, and then for the remaining, convert the `data` to `listitem`

```
data class RawData(val type: String, val data: Data)
interface Converter {
    fun convert(data: Data): ListItem
}

fun transform(): List<ListItem> {
    val providerTypeMap = modelViewProvider.associateBy({it.type}, {it})

    return rawDataList.filter { 
        converter[it.type] != null
    }.map {
        converter[it.type]?.create(it.data) ?: object: ListItem {}
    }
}
```

Note: I want the return type as `List<ListItem>` and not `List<ListItem?>`. In order to do that, I need to have this line

```
converter[it.type]?.create(it.data) ?: object: ListItem {}
```

Which to me the `?` and `?:` is pretty ugly since we know by then, we already filter and only keep that `converter[it.type] != null`

Is there a way for me to get rid of the `?` and `?: ListItem{}` in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution:

```
return rawDataList.mapNotNull {
    converter[it.type]?.create(it.data)
}
```

But i don't know in which Kotlin's version `mapNotNull()` method appeared. If you haven't it you can use construction `map {}.filterNotNull()` or write your own mapNotNull extension method.

Comment: Nice one @Alexandr